# How to take user input on RIDE IDE (Robot Framework)

Tags: python, robotframework-ide

So I am trying to automate logging in to Gmail, but it requires that you enter a phone number to get a code.  Now I was wondering if there was any way to take user input in RIDE IDE so it automatically fills the code box with the entered user input.

This is what I did so far

```
Open Browser    ${URL}  Chrome
Maximize Browser Window     
Set Selenium Implicit Wait  5   
Input Text  id=identifierId ${UID}
Click Element   //span[text()='Next']   
Input Password  //div[@id='password']//input    ${PWD}
Sleep   1   
Click Element   //span[text()='Next']   
Input Text  name=deviceAddress  111-222-3333
Sleep   1   
Click Element   //input[@type = 'submit']   
Sleep   1   
Execute Manual Step    Please Enter the Code    
Sleep   1   
Click Element   //input[@type = 'submit']
```

I found a temporary solution which is Execute Manual Step which allows you to pause the run and manually enter the code you receive but I don't find this solution automated enough.

If you guys could possibly show me how to get user input it would be really helpful!

Comment: Could you please provide some code to support your answer?

Comment: Updated! Feel free to respond with any ideas you might have! @Wojtek T

Comment: Are you _specifically_ asking about getting input in RIDE, or as you asking about how to get input when you run a robotframework test? RIDE and robotframework are two different things.

Comment: getting input in ride @BryanOakley